# Magento 2.3.4: 500 Internal Server Error while sending email from Admin

Tags: magento2.3

When I send email form the magento admin then i can see 500 Internal server error. See attachment. Can you guys help me to resolve this?[image]

Comment: any erro in log ???

Comment: There are no error log. I checked in var folder. I mean error log is not generated.

Comment: 500 errors mean it is not caught by Magento. Check `/var/log/httpd/error_log` for apache & `/var/log/nginx/error.log` for nginx server.